# Dataframe.plot() not working when ax is defined

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to emulate the span selector for the data I have according to the example shown here (https://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/span_selector.html).
However, my data is in a dataframe & not an array.
When I plot the data by itself with the using the code below

```
input_month='2017-06'
plt.close('all')

KPI_ue_data.loc[input_month].plot(x='Order_Type', y='#_Days_@_Post_stream')

plt.show()
```

the data chart is shown perfectly.

However when i am trying to put this into a subplot with the code below (only first two lines are added & ax=ax in the plot line), nothing shows up. I get no error either!!! can anyone help?

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(211, facecolor='#FFFFCC')

input_month='2017-06'
plt.close('all')

KPI_ue_data.loc[input_month].plot(x='Order_Type', y='#_Days_@_Post_stream',ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

Comment: figured it out! i had to remove `plt.close('all')` line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually just set x, y from the dataframe and use ax.plot(x, y). For your code, it should look something like this:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(211, facecolor='#FFFFCC')

input_month='2017-06'
#plt.close('all')

x = KPI_ue_data.loc[(input_month), 'Order_Type']
y = KPI_ue_data.loc[(input_month), '#_Days_@_Post_stream']

ax.plot(x, y)

plt.show()
```